# Clearing Cookies in Objective C ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies

In my app users login through a SafariWebViewController and I am trying to implement a logout button for my app. When the button is pressed the following code is called.

```
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage 
    sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The code does not properly clear the cookies and when the user tries to login the SafariWebViewController remembers their last login. I am not sure what I am doing wrong that the cookies are not clearing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSHTTPCookieStorage` only affects `UIWebView` and your own app's requests, it doesn't have any effect on `WKWebView` or `SFSafariViewController`, they use their own cookie handler.

`SFSafariViewController` also shares cookies with the Safari app; my guess is only the user can clear the cache themselves (for obvious security/privacy reasons).

Use `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` if you want to control the cache.